# Finding all schemes/hosts from an app's manifest on Android

Tags: java, android, intentfilter

I'm trying to get a list of all the intent filters containing VIEW and BROWSABLE (and specifically, all the schemes and hosts) of a specific app using package manager.

So far I've managed to be able to check if a package contains a scheme only after using intent.setData(checkedScheme) explicitly.

Is there a known solution?